# MySQL Specialization/Generalization questions

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, erd, specialization

So I have found out that I need to do a specialization Hierarchies model, however I can't quite figure out how to code it. I have found some information on how to do generalization.

My question is: is it the same way to code it but different way to express it?

Let's take this as an example:

[image: Model]
<sub>(source: [javaguicodexample.com](http://www.javaguicodexample.com/erdrelationalmodelnotes_files/erdrelationalmodelnotes010.png))</sub>

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
            EmpNo                  INTEGER,
            EmpName                VARCHAR(30),
            EmpHireDate            DATE,
            CONSTRAINT PKEmployee PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo)
);
 
CREATE TABLE SalaryEmp(
            EmpNo         INTEGER,
            EmpSalary     DECIMAL(10,2),
            CONSTRAINT PKSalaryEmp PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo),
            CONSTRAINT FKSalaryEmp FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES Employee ON DELETE CASCADE
);
 
CREATE TABLE HourlyEmp(
            EmpNo          INTEGER,
            EmpRate        DECIMAL(10,2),
            CONSTRAINT PKHourlyEmp PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo),
            CONSTRAINT FKHourlyEmp FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES Employee ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

is this how it should be coded?
and the ERD should look like this one?

[image: ERD]